# Confusion Regarding Weibel's exercise on the $n^{th}$ homology functor $H_n(-)$ of chain complexes

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring (I think $R$ can be any ring, not even necessarily unital or commutative) and let $C=\{C_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ and $D = \{D_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ be chain complexes of $R$-modules equipped with differentials $d_n$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $d_n'$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ respectively.

My question is two fold:

> (i) Let $u:C\to D$ be a morphism in **Ch(mod-R)**. Then according to Weibel's *Homological Algebra* pdf, we have $u_{n-1}d_n=d_{n-1}'u_n$(1) $\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$ (1), and he says that this means that the following diagram commutes:
> [image]
> but I think the equation (1) should say $u_{n-1}d_n=d_n'u_n$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$ (2) instead, right? (otherwise I have no idea what is happening, I think (2) is precisely what it means for this diagram to commute. To be clear, the vertical maps are $u_n:C_n\to D_n$, and the horizontal maps are $d_n':D_n\to D_{n-1}$ and $d_n:C_n\to C_{n-1}$, I don't think the composition $d_{n-1}'u_n$ needs to be defined).

> (ii) Is my guess correct that if $u:C\to D$ is a morphism in **Ch(mod-R)**, then $H_n(u)$ is the $R$-module homomorphism:
> $H_n(C)\to H_n(D)$
> $a+B_n(C)\mapsto u_n(a)+B_n(D)$?

(clearly we must have $H_n(u):H_n(C)\to H_n(D)$, and via some computations which assume that my statements in (i) are correct, it can be seen that $ker d_n \subset ker u_{n-1}d_n= ker d_n'u_n$ and $u_n(im d_{n+1})\subset im(d_{n+1}')$, so we have that my purposed map in (ii) is in fact an $R$-module homomorphism).

(I tried to tex what I have as a picture there using tikzcd and I added the tikzcd package but it still said unrecognized environment) [By the way this regards exercise 1.1.2 of Weibel but nothing in that other related MSE post answers any of my questions I am fairly certain.]

Comment: As for the TeX question, the system here is not TeX but MathJax which is less powerful. You can put commutative diagram, but the only way (I believe) is with the AMScd package. [see here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference#answer-16888)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct with both of your assertions.

I haven't read much of Weibel's book and while I think it is a fantastic book, many people warn that there are a lot of typos. So while studying you might find it helpful to have the [list of errata](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Eweibel/Hbook.errors.edition2.pdf) close by. As an example the very first erratum answers your (1).

Comment: Thank you!! Much Appreciated.